# How does this sed command works?

Tags: shell, sed, command-line-interface

I came across the following sed command which I found here https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub:

```
ps -ef | sed -n '/grunt/{/grep/!p;}'
```

Could someone explain me how does the `sed` part work? What's the purpose of `{/grep/!p;}`?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: compare the output of these two commands `ps -ef | sed -n '/grunt/p'` and .`ps -ef | sed -n '/grunt/{/grep/!p;}'`  You will notice later is not printing one additional like which contains process id of the grep command you hit. This would be equivalent to `ps -ef |grep grunt |grep -v grep`. Its like print all the lines containing `grunt` but not the line also containing `grep` in it.

Comment: Thanks, please, write an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compare the output of following  two commands:

`ps -ef | sed -n '/grunt/p'` and `ps -ef | sed -n '/grunt/{/grep/!p;}'`.

You will notice later is not printing one additional like which contains process id of the grep command you hit. This would be equivalent to:

`ps -ef |grep grunt |grep -v grep`

Its like print all the lines containing grunt but not the line also containing grep in it

Comment: ....and of course when faced with using chains of piped `grep`s or a sed command other than `s/old/new/` you should just use one awk command instead. In this case it'd be `ps -ef | awk '/grunt/ && !/awk/'` or even better use `pgrep`.